# Changing Windows locales on a per-process basis

Tags: windows, process, locale

Is there any way to change the Windows locale only for a particular program?

I have one or two programs that don't work correctly for non-English (U.S.) locales and would like to work around theirs bugs without changing my user-wide locale settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a a bit of a hack that might do it. I believe these settings are configured on a per users basis so I'm guessing you could:

- create a new user
- log in as that user
- setup the required settings for the app
- log out and back in as your normal user
- run the program as the newly created user (you can do this by holding shift then right clicking the exe and chosing "run as")

Comment: Why this answer is accepted? While it sounds as a solution, it is pure fantasy! It is not possible to set locale on the per user basis, language for non-unicode programs is computer (not mere user) wide setting. And there is no such feature as 'run as some other local user', there is only 'run as administrator' option. Maybe it is possible on *nix, but the question was about Windows.

Comment: Sorry about misunderstanding. It is possible to run Windows program as different user.

Answer (score 4):

There's an open-source alternative to Microsoft AppLocale that is claimed to work up to windows 10, available on GitHub:

https://github.com/xupefei/Locale-Emulator

Its allows per-app locale settings, accessible via a context menu option.